# boost::bind as an argument to accept function with n args and use the same on further function calls

Tags: boost, boost-bind

Can i do something like below ? Is it possible or is there any workaround?

```
..
PostWorkToThread( boost::bind(func_x, arg1) );
PostWorkToThread( boost::bind(func_y, arg1, arg2) );
PostWorkToThread( boost::bind(func_z, arg1, arg2, arg3) );
..


void PostWorkToThread( boost::bind xxx )
{
    PostWork( boost::bind(xxx) ); or
    PostWork( xxx );
}
```

Thank you, I appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Since the type of the function object generated by [`boost::bind`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.interface) (and [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)) is not specified, you should make `PostWorkToThread` a template:

```
template< typename Fun >
void PostWorkToThread( Fun xxx )
{
    // Enqueue xxx for execution
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [`boost::function`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/function.html) (or [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)) to erase the type of the function object:

```
void PostWorkToThread( boost::function< void() > const& xxx )
{
    // Enqueue xxx for execution
}
```

Note that in this case `boost::function` (and `std::function`) may have to dynamically allocate memory to store the function object. However, you will likely have to do it anyway to enqueue the function for execution, so this is probably not a problem.